# Writing functions in WordPress functions.php that don't replace a WordPress core function

Tags: functions

Using instructions from the WordPress codex, I have replaced/added to a number of WordPress core and theme functions. For these tasks, code, such as `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_custom_header_setup');` are already putting the code to work in the right place of the processing.

Now, I have a situation where I want to move code from a custom WordPress template in a child theme into `functions.php` and call it from the template file as needed. In this case, essentially, I want to move code into `functions.php` that will include a few layers into a highly customized `front-page.php` after pulling in some custom field data.

Do child theme template files have access to `functions.php` or do I need to add some code somewhere to make that connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child theme will have access to the functions in the parent theme's functions.php. Nothing you need to do.

Comment: I want to put the code in the child theme's functions.php file. Does your answer mean that all templates in the child theme will include (have access to) functions in the child theme's functions.php file?

Comment: Yes, the child theme will also have access to the functions in the functions.php of the child theme's directory, in addition to the functions in the parent theme's directory. :)